# How to append .json file consist of list with open() append mode?

Tags: python, json, append

For example, I have **TEST.json** written as:

```
[{"Alice" : 1, "Betty": 2}]
```

Is there any way to **append current json** as

```
[{"Alice" : 1, "Betty": 2}, {"Alice" : 10, "Betty": 20}]
```

by using 'with open append mode' method? ex:

```
with open("TEST.json", "a+") as f:
    json.dump(blablabla)
```

As I have to edit about 60 millions of files, so, I'm not gonna use the code like:

```
with open("TEST.json", "r") as f:
   data = json.load(f)

appended_data = data.append({"Alice" : 10, "Betty": 20})

with open("TEST.json", "w") as f:
   json.dump(appended_data, f)
```

Comment: @Timus Sorry my bad, Example code just been committed in main text

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what is bothering you with last code: What do you want to avoid? Is it the re-dumping of the _complete_ data? Overall I'd say you could try that code but embed it into a multiprocessing-threading-combo solution (or asyncio instead of threading)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you're looking for:

```
with open('TEST.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    json.dump([{"Alice" : 1, "Betty": 2}], file, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)

with open('TEST.json', 'r+', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data.append({"Alice" : 10, "Betty": 20})
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)
```

Comment: I don't think so: That's essentially the same as the code op want's to avoid, except for one less `open`. I guess the idea is more to remove the `]` at the end, append the new data without `[` at the beginning, etc. Otherwise the complete data has to be rewritten to the disk. Just my guess, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Timus, hmm, mb it's better to try not to use `[...]` and stick to the normal json format if possible

Comment: @Timus I was thinking of that idea either because while using the write mode (I mean 'w' or 'r+', execution time will be run over following increasing  exponential function

Comment: @DmitriiDavs Well.. I have to use list type in order to check if there's a duplicate of new data with previous data